# postgresql cannot insert from table Cannot insert

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am working on a PostgreSQL table that takes data from one table and inserts it into another.

i created a table:

```
create table temp_appearance (firstname text, lastname text, position text, media text);
```

and populated it with data.

I then created a new table:

```
create table actors (id serial primary key ,firstname text, lastname text, position text);
```

But when I insert into actors from temp_appearance:

```
 insert into actors (firstname, lastname, position) 
 select firstname, lastname, position from temp_appearance;
```

it gives me this error:
ERROR: COLUMN "firstname" does not exist
HINT: There is a column named "firstname" in table "actors", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

I cant figure out why it is donig this since these same commands have worked on postgreSQL on other computers. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i seem to have figured it out. It doesnt like having the same name for the insert column as well as the from column, so i changed it too

```
temp_appearance(id serial, fname text, lname text, position text)
```

which now works since fname and firstname are different column names. Weird i didn't see that in the documentation.
Thanks!